# Parse & Swift : logInViewController.fields

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to customize the Parse Log In View Controller (adding or removing fields) in my new Swift Project.

First I tried to add this (as said in official parse tutorial) :

```
logInViewController.fields = PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton | PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton | PFLogInFieldsPasswordForgotten
```

This was the error returned:

```
'PFLoginFields' is not convertible to 'Bool'
```

Next, I tried the solution mentioned here: [Swift: Could not find an overload for '|' that accepts the supplied arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132244/swift-could-not-find-an-overload-for-that-accepts-the-supplied-arguments)

This solution returned the following error on **Xcode 6 beta 4** :

```
'PFLoginFields' does not have a member named 'value'
```

Anyone have a solution working with this Xcode 6b4 ?

*(sorry for my English, not my mother language)*

Comment: see this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996787/parse-baas-ios-loginfields-in-swift-value-should-be-changed-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse changed the names in their last update:

use

```
PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword
```

instead of

```
PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword
```

I also experienced some other problems after applying this change but give it a try and update us how it went!